# TQDM on pandas df.describe()

Tags: pandas, progress-bar, tqdm

I saw that TQDM has implemented its progress bar for pandas but in the documentation it only describe the usage for the `.apply` method.
I was wondering if it's possible to implement TQDM progress bar on other pandas operation like for example `df.describe()`.

If this is not possible, is there a way to at least be sure that your Jupiter notebook is still working or is it crashed? eh eh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
tqdm.pandas(desc="my bar!")
df.progress_apply(lambda x: x.describe())
```

Although it doesn't seem to be useful.